# why does this search of a mysql database produce no results? Using LIKE for the first time

Tags: php, mysql

Editing someone else's code here, so I can't change the field in the database called `title` or change to MySQLi etc :/

The code connects to the DB without problems, but always pulls in zero results.

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM newproducts WHERE 'title' LIKE ('%$q%')";
$sql = mysql_query($strSQL) or die(mysql_error());
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

if ( $q == '' ) {
    echo '<p class="black-text">Please provide a search term.</p>';
}

else if ( $num_rows <= 0 ) {
    echo '<p class="black-text">Your search for <b>'.$q.'</b> returned <b>0</b> results.</p>';
}

else { 

    echo '<p class="black-text">Your search for <b>'.$q.'</b> returned <b>'.$num_rows.'</b> result(s).<br/><br/>';  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        echo '- '.$row['title'].' <a href="'.$row['link'].'.html" class="search-link">[Read more]</a><br/>';
    }
    echo '</p>';
}
```

Could it be a case issue? I've tried searching for lower and upper strings, but still zero results.

Comment: what happens when you run that query directly against the database?

Comment: Please pay attention to Steve's advice to avoid using `mysql_query`. If you continue to use it you will accumulate a large amount of technical debt that you'll have to address, plus you'll build all kinds of bad habits that won't be easy to undo. [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php) are the most effective way to write proper queries that aren't subject to SQL injection bugs.

Comment: Read the first line of my post @tadman `Editing someone else's code here, so I can't change the field in the database called title or change to MySQLi etc :/`

Comment: Then I hope this code is studded with appropriate levels of `mysql_real_escape_string` because there isn't any in this snippet and that's always a very bad sign.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MySQL single quotes denote strings:

```
SELECT * FROM newproducts WHERE 'title' LIKE ('%$q%')
```

Should be

```
SELECT * FROM newproducts WHERE title LIKE ('%$q%')
```

Additionally, you are testing for `if ($q == '')` after you have performed the query - you may want to do that before - but that isn't causing your issue.

And lastly, you are at risk of SQL injection by using potentially unsafe user input - but I'm not going to delve into that as it isn't directly related to your question. Most PHP developers are using prepared statements these days to make their queries safer (and because the old style of running queries is going to be deprecated).

Comment: Oddly enough, I removed the single quotes and it works! Weird! Thanks Steve!! :)

Comment: You would use back-ticks rather than single quotes for this, i.e. ` rather than '.